# exports in .bashrc not working

Tags: bash

I have a program `.path.py` which prints an export command for `PATH`. In my `.bashrc` I have an entry at the top `$(python $HOME/.prefix/.path.py)` except that when I login over ssh, or even run `source $HOME/.bashrc` those paths are not exported. Manually running `$(python $HOME/.prefix/.path.py)` works fine though. On other linux systems I've used this method normally works fine, it's just on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop that it isn't.

Can anyone help me fix this? Comment with any additional information which would be helpful. Please note there are no newlines in this text, only spaces.

```
export PATH=/home/username/.prefix/calc/bin:/home/username/.prefix/misc/bin:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/bin:/home/username/.prefix/calc/bin:/home/username/.prefix/misc/bin:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/bin:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/intel/bin/ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include:/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include:/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include: LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64: C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include:/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include:/home/username/.prefix/calc/include:/home/username/.prefix/misc/include:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/include: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/calc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib:/home/username/.prefix/misc/lib64:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib:/home/username/.prefix/testu01/lib64:
```

Comment: Can you show the part of the .bashrc that uses that script and a sample output of that script?

Comment: @Salem I've added some sample output. The .bashrc` script simply contains the line `$(python $HOME/.prefix/.path.py)`

Comment: BTW, you have a trialling colon at the end

Answer (score 5):

`~/.bashrc` is only sourced for non-login shells, so it's not sourced when you log in using ssh.

Use `.bash_profile` instead.

Related: 
http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: Oh...where should that script be then?

Comment: Added information to answer.

Comment: Thanks. Should `.bash_profile` source Ubuntu's `.profile` since it has a comment saying if `.bash_profile` exists it won't be sourced?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu this method does in fact work. However, there is a line in the default `.bashrc` that sets PATH without the existing PATH. My script needed to be moved to the bottom of `.bashrc`.